# php - ctype_xdigit returning nothing (or FALSE?)

Tags: php, hex

Here is the bit of code that I'm having trouble with. Both $id and $data are Hex strings.

```
public function __construct($id, $data){
    echo $data . "<br/>";
    echo "DATA HEX:" . ctype_xdigit($data) . "<br/>";
    echo "ID HEX:" . ctype_xdigit($id) . "<br/>";
}
```

Here is some of what gets outputted when I call this function (repeatedly):

```
34030040 
DATA HEX:
ID HEX:1
00B0B38000 
DATA HEX:
ID HEX:1
47000300565C3FFF 
DATA HEX:
ID HEX:1
00001020 
DATA HEX:
ID HEX:1
...
```

I've checked using `gettype()` and the type of $data is definitely a string. If I take one of these strings and put it into `ctype_xdigit()`, I get a 1 as the result. Am I missing something obvious? It seems weird that it works for one of them and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

There was a newline after the `$data` hex string leftover from parsing the file it came from.